# Input tag of type "color" not rendered in IOS

Tags: c#, ios, blazor, blazor-server-side, html-input

I need a color and time picker for my project. To achieve this, I am using the HTML tag "input" of type "color" and "time".

```
<div>
   Color: <input type="color" />
</div>
<div>
   Time: <input type="time" />
</div>
```

On my Windows machine this works well. [Working input on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWWDL.png)

On Android the input controls are also rendered properly:[Working input on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8Dqx.jpg)

If I open the site on my iPhone, the input controls are not properly rendered:[Not working input on IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/US62z.png)
The device dependent color or time picker will not be opened. I have also tried it with another browser, but same result.
It seems to work, if the render-mode in _Hosts.cshtml is changed from "ServerPrerendered" to "Static". With this setting, the input controls are rendered correct, but the NavMenu ist not working.

For test purposes I created a Blazor Client Side project (Blazor WebAssembly App). Same result, the controls are rendered wrong.

Why are the controls rendered properly with "render-mode=Static" and not with "render-mode=ServerPrerendered"?
Is it possible to get the controls working with "render-mode=ServerPrerendered"?

**Edit:**

There is a JavaScripte file linked in "_Hosts.cshtml"

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

If this line is removed, the input control is shown correct.
But I do not know what causes the problem in this file.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a bug of WebKit. This link can be useful
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4689

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am not quite shure if this is bug related to WebKit.
In some situations the control is properly rendered (e.g. if render-mode is set to "Static" or if <input type="color"/> is defined in _Hosts.cshtml).